# How to enable all disabled form select options without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-select

I have a HTML form with a few select elements. One of the option in each of these elements has been disabled initially. Example:

```
<label>Amount: <select name="amount">
    <option selected value='0'>Any</option>
    <option value="1">100+</option>
    <option value="2">200+</option>
    <option value="3">500+</option>
    <option disabled value="4">Specify</option>
</select></label>
```

I need to enable them with javascript. Is there a good way to target these elements without using jQuery?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` is great for modern browsers (just check for the disabled attribute).  Targeting older?

Comment: Yes, I noted that it only work for modern browsers.

Comment: k.  Then I would feature detect and use Amit's for modern browsers, with a fallback like Rob's for older.

Comment: Look, there is support for querySelectorAll even in IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will take care of all disabled elements and is simple.

You can do this:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[disabled]'); // target all disabled elemnts
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].removeAttribute('disabled'); // enable them.
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/m8jVe/)

Comment: This feature is 92% supported. I think I will pick yours for its efficiency. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped. ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "92% supported"? :P

Answer (score 2):

**JS:**

```
var ddl = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (var m = 0; m < ddl.length; m++) {
   for (var i = 0; i < ddl[m].length; i++) {
      ddl[m].options[i].disabled = false;
   }
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/9ZT7N/1/).

Comment: I have a few select elements, not just this one.

Comment: RobG's solution would be better since both are looping through all options. +1 for the effort though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable every option element in the document, you can do:

```
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  options[i].disabled = false;
}
```

If you want to enable only the options for a specific select element, first get a reference to it then use its [options](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-select-options) collection:

```
var options = select.options;
// continue as as above...
```